# How to use dynamic routing in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am developing a dashboard application using React. I am having some issues understanding `react-router`. How can we use the dynamic route and render a component?

My app has a few static routes like `/user`, `/profile` and `/dashboard`. I am rendering `User`, `Profile` and `Dashboard` components for the routes. When the user logs in, the server will send JSON response which contains, user id, type, and other fields. I want to change the routing path to `/dashboard/45` (45 is userId) for this user after a successful login. In the end, the `Dashboard` component will render different elements based on `userId` and `userType`.

```
<Route 
path='/dashboard'
exact={true}
render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} user={user} handleChildFunc= 
{this.handleChildFunc}/>}/>
```

What is missing in this code? I am not sure what to google or which tutorial to follow. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
<Route exact path='/feed/:id' component={
  (props) =>
    <Feed
       postId={props.match.params.id}
    />
}/>
```

Then the id can be accessed inside Feed using props.postId e.g.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  if (props.postId) { 
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Now I will try to make nested routes like /dashboard/45/units/devices etc.